# How can I tell if all the hardware in my system has correctly installed drivers?

Tags: drivers

I'm working on making the switch from Windows to Ubuntu.  Does Ubuntu have an equivalent to "Device Manager"?  What I want to do is check if all of the hardware in the machine has correctly installed drivers. (without having to run a plethora of individual lsusb, lspci, modprobe, etc.  I'm not quite there yet.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dash, type in "test" and it will show a test suite.When started it will take a while collecting and then show this:

[image]

It will take a while but the end result will be a full report.

Besides that... if you do no run into crashes or get error notices it basically works. Ubuntu (Linux in general) uses generic drivers. So if you can use it it works ;)

For you graphics card there is an alternative to go 3rd party (proprietary).

Dash, search for "software & updates":

[image]

Comment: Now that Unity is no longer there, how to run `test`? I ran `test` in the terminal but it seems that that command is for something else

Answer (score 5):

The situation is rather different with Linux, because most drivers are included with the kernel, so there's not the same need to compare what is installed and running with what is available from various websites. As long as you keep your package manager up to date, it will inform you of any updates.

But you can install a package called hardware info, with it you can find a lot information about your hardware similar to device manager, and more.  You can generate a complete system report.

Plus, if you haven't installed Ubuntu yet, you can choose try Ubuntu, to make sure that all your hardware is working.

[image]

Here is a comparison between [Hard Info](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3gw8p8o5n3fevvo/hardinfo_report.html), and [System Testing](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pvtn0jyjziy1sor/submission.xml)

Comment: I can't find this package.  Do you know the exact name?

Comment: For system Testing, just search for test in dash.  For hard Info, just type this in terminal `sudo apt-get install hardinfo`

Answer (score 1):

You can also go to Start --> Additional drivers and then Ubuntu will report if there is any outdated or recommended driver. Remember that older and propietary drivers may show up, thats completely normal.