# Spec check program for ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there a program for ubuntu in checking system specs? I've tried the onbard one that comes with ubuntu but it Only shows me the amount of memory, Graphics, CPU and Sound - although I need alot more than that as they're stil only brief descriptions. Motherboard and such needs to be included too

Comment: Take a look at my [Post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/315528/how-can-i-tell-if-all-the-hardware-in-my-system-has-correctly-installed-drivers/315537#315537), see if its what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Sysinfo is what you are looking for in Ubuntu 18.04 and earlier. It is a graphical user interface application that supplies information about the hardware in your system including CPU, memory, graphics card and the motherboard. You can install Sysinfo using the Ubuntu Software Center, or else open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install sysinfo
```

[image]

In Ubuntu 20.04 and later install System Profiler ( `sudo apt install hardinfo` ) instead of Sysinfo.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

`lspci` shows everything what your pci bus have eaten

`lsusb` does the same for usb

For the motherboard, you should be very aware of electronics to detect motherboard by just on it's devices. I suggest to open the case and see.