# Logitech presenter R800 set-up problem on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (64-bit)

Tags: 18.04, hardware

- I am on **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (64-bit)** on my Asus notebook and I am trying to setup the **USB presenter by Logitech R800**.

I searched on plenty of Linux forums (also on Logitech community forum, specifically)  and could not find any solution for my problem, which is the failure to recognize the USB receiver that comes with the Logitech R800 presenter. This causes the presenter device not to work at all.

As I do not have experience with Ubuntu - or any other Linux distribution, really - I look for detailed and step-by-step information, please.

*Aiming at elaborating better what is happening, please, guide me with the right questions and suggestions, if needed.*

This is the best I can express this problem.

I hope to get a response.

Thank you!

Related:[Is Logitech's Unifying receiver supported?](https://askubuntu.com/q/113984/66509)

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/315528/how-can-i-tell-if-all-the-hardware-in-my-system-has-correctly-installed-drivers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Logitech Presenter uses the Logitech Unifying USB receiver, open the Ubuntu Software app and install Solaar.

You can also Google "Solaar" for more info.

note: you'll have to do the initial setup of the dongle in Windows, using the Logitech Unifying Software.

Comment: I think that link for [`solaar` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=Solaar) will be very useful. Also you may add link to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/113984/66509).

Comment: This information helped a lot in start solving the problem.